# BSD crashing after creating ZFS pool

Tags: freebsd, zfs

I've just installed FreeBSD 10.1 on a virtual machine (using Oracle VirtualBox), and I'm attempting to enable and setup ZFS.

I did the following commands:

`# mkdir /tut/` - from root dir

`# echo 'zfs_enable="YES"' >> /etc/rc.conf`

`# cd /tut`

`# truncate -s 2G file1` (and 3 more times for file2, file3, file4)

`# zpool create mypool raidz1 /tut/file1 /tut/file2 /tut/file3 /tut/file4`

And then the system crashes. First - any ideas what's happening? And next, where can I find the proper crash information (`/var/crash/core.text.0` ? which part, if so?) to copy to here, so you can see what's going on?

I will say - I was able to run `# zfs list` before it crashed, and it gave the output I was expecting (info about the pool I just made), but post-crash, it now tells me: `no datasets available`.

Comment: Hmmm....why use ZFS on a VirtualBox machine?

Comment: @mdpc I am learning how to use it (and BSD, really) before putting it on a real hard drive